# Defining a macro using input string and input value inside a function in c

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I want to define a preprocessor inside a function using input string and value given by user.

```
#include<stdio.h> 

void main() 
{
  char st[10]; 
  int a; 

  printf("Enter string:"); 
  scanf("%s",st); 
  printf("Enter Value:"); 
  scanf("%d",&a);

  //Here I want to define a preprocessor using input values.
  //Suppose input given is HELLO and 3 I should define as #define HELLO 3 and use it later in the function. 
}
```

Is there any possible way to achieve this.

I am not sure on how it is done. Couldn't find any possible help from many sources. The user gives input string and value according to which preprocessor changes.
Suppose I have ["MSG1","MSG2","MSG3"] and [10,13,15] which are given as user input then I need to define macros like #define MSG1 10,#define MSG2 13 and #define MSG3 15.
Hope the question is clear and understandable of what I am expecting to achieve. Any suggestions do let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pre-processor macros are executed during compilation so they won't help you with a runtime variable.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/209820). Maybe you want a hash map? Can give an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @StanlyBabu please don't post lengthy comments but [edit] and put all relevant information into the question. That being said, your requirement doesn't make much sense, you program cannot "create" `#define MSG1 1` etc., once your program runs, defines, variable names, function names etc. are gone. What are you _actually_ trying to achieve?

Comment: Also format your code properly (for example like the samples in your C learning material). I've done it for you

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thnaks.So to be clear, I have a function call in which I need to pass the arguments. I can pass it directly using array indexing to keep track of what I am passing I might need #define statements is what I believe. If I can achieve it using different technique do let me know.

Comment: To me it is still unclear what _it_ is that you want to achieve. What exactly would you pass to the function if you had the macros, and what would the function do therewith?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any possible way to achieve this.

No. C programming language is compiled. The source code is fixed and lost after compilation, and C code can't modify itself.

> how it is done
>
> Suppose I have ["MSG1","MSG2","MSG3"] and [10,13,15] which are given as user input

It is done *in C* code. You would implement a map *in C programming language* that stores the name and value of each user input and references them, you would also implement all the relevant functions and abstractions needed to work with that abstraction. The data may be represented with something along `struct elem { char *name; int value; }; struct map { struct elem *elems; size_t count; };` depending on the actual data you want to store.

The overall abstraction here is a scripting programming language, where the code given by user is processed *by* a program written in for example C programming language. *Then* you can define your own variables *in that scripting language*, which internally is being processed *by* a program that stores, processes, references all variables.